# C# multiple build configurations in 1 output assembly

Tags: c#, compilation

I have a C# project, which is going to be used in multiple projects. For the correct use of the library a compile symbol is neccesary.

This is one example part of the code

```
public class ComputedForeignKeyAttribute
#if !EFADDMIGRATION
    : ForeignKeyAttribute
#else
    : NotMappedAttribute
#endif
{
    public ComputedForeignKeyAttribute(string name)
#if !EFADDMIGRATION
    : base(name)
#endif
    { }
}
```

So if the `EFADDMIGRATION` symbol is used, I switch the build configuration. For running the code I need to switch back to `DEBUG` or `RELEASE`.

When moving the code into an external project (outside of the solution), is there any way to create an assembly that reacts to those symbols as well?

```
Project A references Library C
Project A references Library C
Project A is in solution 1
Project B is in solution 2
Library C is in solution 3
```

Compiling Project A with `DEBUG` results in the `ComputedForeignKeyAttribute` to inherit from `NotMappedAttribute`, but compiling with `EFADDMIGRATION` will result in the Attribute will inherit from `ForeignKeyAttribute`.

Is there a way of a multi symbol assembly build? Or is there another way for example by using the `[ConditionalAttribute]`?

For those who are interrested why I need this. We use computed foreign keys, which EntityFrameworkCore does not support. Therefore for the `add-migration` process we just change the build configuration to avoid migration errors. During execution we want to fetch those relations by telling EntityFramework that those fields are foreign keys.

Comment: What do you mean by a multi-symbol assembly build? Are you searching for a way to define the value of the "EFADDMIGRATION" directive?

Comment: Make an EFADDMIGRATION build configuration for Debug and Release, with EFAM or something in the path.

Comment: I'm searching a mechanism, where I can change the Inheritance of the ComputedForeignKeyAttribute. When using symbols and compile using DEBUG an assembly with the DEBUG configuration will be compiled. When using the EF build configuration another assembly will be compiled. I may miss out something here. When switching between build configurations the library code needs so switch too.